# Using select2 ajax remote data with json file

Tags: javascript, json, jquery-select2

Trying to get this to work but with no luck yet. I created a json file in the root of my site granting it access in the htaccess file so it is accessible in browser using **localhost/places.json**

An example of the file below

```
[
    {
        "city": "Lagos", 
        "admin": "Lagos", 
        "country": "Nigeria", 
        "population_proper": "1536", 
        "iso2": "NG", 
        "capital": "minor", 
        "lat": "6.454066", 
        "lng": "3.394673", 
        "population": "9466000"
    }, 
    {
        "city": "Kano", 
        "admin": "Kano", 
        "country": "Nigeria", 
        "population_proper": "3140000", 
        "iso2": "NG", 
        "capital": "admin", 
        "lat": "12.002381", 
        "lng": "8.51316", 
        "population": "3140000"
    }, 
...
]
```

In my js file i have this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.js-data-example-ajax').select2({
  ajax: {
    url: 'http://localhost/places.json',
    dataType: 'json',
    type: "get",
    delay: 250,
    data: function (params) {
    return {
      searchTerm: params.term // search term
    };
   },
   processResults: function (response) {
     return {
        results: response.city
     };
   },
  }
});
</script>
```

I am expecting to get the searched result when typed but it turns up with

> no result found

Please what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Just to get this out of the way; if you navigate to http://localhost/places.json you can see the JSON file? Any console errors?

Comment: Yes i do see the file with no errors

Comment: In `processResults`, you need to replace `response.city` with `response.map(item => ({ id: item.city, text: item.city }))` (select2 expects [this](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats), and `response` is the entire response)

Comment: Yeah that works. But one small thing. I don't know if it is because my json file does not have an id identifier or something else but when i type a city it does not match with the option. It just shows the drop-down with the first option highlighted.

Comment: I tested this and if you look at the console, select2 is appending the search term to the url as query param and running ajax again. So you're apparently supposed to pre-filter on the server, which makes sense. This means you cannot use a static file though.